# Can I use the "Scan" button with SANE?

Tags: scanner, sane

I have an HP Deskjet with integrated scanner. It has a "Scan" button on its top, but this button does not interact with the `xsane` program on my Debian machine: To get a page scanned, I have to initiate the scanning process from `xsane`.

Is there a setting (or a scan program) that allows me to press the scan button and cause the program to scan a page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the scanner's buttons are supported by sane you can use [scanbd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scanbd/) to make them functional. You can find detailed instructions [here](http://thehomeserverhandbook.com/2012/03/03/scanbd_part1/).

Comment: Archived link, as the original does not work anymore: https://web.archive.org/web/20201031152413/https://thehomeserverhandbook.com/2012/03/03/scanbd_part1/

Comment: And here too, in case the archived vanishes: https://i.imgur.com/hFkKu4W.png , https://i.imgur.com/nSEwuR1.png , https://i.imgur.com/dfb1kpJ.png (3 pages)

Comment: The repository has moved [to Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/sane-project/frontend/scanbd).