# saned accepting scans initiated on scanner/MFP

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, scanner, sane

I'd like to use my Raspberry Pi as a home print and scanner server. I successfully made it to half way, installed hplips and cups, we can print now from OSX, Windows, Ubuntu and Android, there's sane/saned and I can scan from the command line.

I'm wondering if there's a way to set it up so that when I push the scan button on my multifunctional device, it saves the scan with default settings and an incremental file name in a folder that's shared with samba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a solution for this. It's mentioned and referred here:
[Can I use the "Scan" button with SANE?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134740/can-i-use-the-scan-button-with-sane?rq=1)

Update as per HalosGhost's comment below:

This can be solved by the scan button daemon, scanbd. The project's homepage can be found at [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scanbd/) and [The Home Server Handbook](https://thehomeserverhandbook.com/2012/03/03/scanbd_part1/) provided a step-by-step guide 4 years ago on how to download the source (plus the required libraries) and compile it, now the whole thing is available in a package. So on Debian, or just as in my case, on Raspbian you just do a:

```
sudo apt-get install scanbd
```

Both scanbd and scanbm have a mab page to take the first steps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145911)

Comment: Good advice, just did that!